# Using an API for a magnetic swiper however device will not open

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a plugin written in objective-c. I am using the MagTek API, and it will not recognize that the device is open... If the the code is in ViewDidLoad it opens the device, but I cannot have my code there now I can only have it the method that my JS will call. Why is it not "opening" my device:

```
-(void)enableSwipe:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

   AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);
   self.magSwipe                = (MTSCRA *)([delegate getSCRALib]);
   [self.magSwipe setDeviceType:MAGTEKAUDIOREADER];
   [self.magSwipe openDevice];


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(trackDataReady:)
                                             name:@"trackDataReadyNotification"
                                           object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Where is this `enableSwipe:` method and whose property is `magSwipe`?

Comment: Its in a `MagSwipe` `@implementation`. `magSwipe` is an instance of the `MTSCRA` class

Comment: `enableSwipe:` method gets called by my javascript

Comment: Do you get any compilation errors / how are you debugging this? What do you get of you put a `NSLog (@"%@",self.magSwipe);` before adding the observer?

Comment: I set breakpoints, and after I even set the device name it shows that everything under `magSwipe` is nil. I am at loss.

Comment: that probably means that for some reason appDelegate's `getSCRALib` returns `nil` - i'd look there first

Answer (score 3):

I just spent half a day figuring this one out, I think your problem is the same as the one I had based on the way you described it. You code is probably fine, the issue for me was that there's a key you need to set in the info.plist file for the project in order to get the strip reader to fire off it's NSNotification containing swipe data. The key you need to set is:

Supported external accessory protocols > Array
  Item 0 > String > com.magtek.idynamo

Once you do that it should work as documented in the sample project that Magtek provides. As far as I know this isn't documented anywhere, but if anyone knows where it is please link to it.

Comment: This was a while ago, from what I remember I had to set up more notifications. I forget exactly what I did, nor do I have the source code anymore.

Comment: Are there different protocol strings for different magtek devices? Say com.magtek.idynamo for the iDynamo and com.magtek.kdynamo for the kDynamo for example.